# Commenting the printing line causes change in logic

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying  to create a multi-threaded program and if I comment out the printing line of the running then the logic will change and print the first three as the winners. if not commented then this works correctly and prints correctly their position.

```
package beans;
import java.lang.Thread;

class xyz extends Thread
{
    String a;
    static int k=1;
    xyz(String c)
    {
        a=c;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<15;i++)
        {
        System.out.println(a+" is running in "+i+"km");
        if(k==1 && i==14)
        {
            System.out.println(a+" is the winner");
            k++;

        }
        else if(k>1 && i==14)
        {
            System.out.println(a+" is in "+k+ "place");
            k++;
        }

        }
    }
}

public class abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        xyz t1= new xyz("car");
        t1.start();
        xyz t2= new xyz("bike");
        t2.start();
        xyz t3= new xyz("cycle");
        t3.start();
        xyz t4= new xyz("walk");
        t4.start();
        xyz t5= new xyz("arjun");
        t5.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program is not thread-safe. First of all, `k++` operations on a static variable should be synchronized or `AtomicInteger` should be used.

Indeterministic behaviour is a very common case when your program is not thread safe. Printing something out affects the way threads are executed what causes that removing these operations might affect your program behaviour (what's absolutely normal but not desired).

There's one more race-condition in your program. Checking the winner condition should also be synchronized.

You should carefully analyse the way threads use the shared `k` variable.